# Parsec: Elegant way to consume and save input

Tags: haskell, parsec, named

I am working for a small web hosting company and decided to write a script to sort our rather large named/bind9 zone configuration file. I'm somewhat happy with the way it turned out (at least it works), but the inelegance of the central parsing function bothers me a bit. For reference, a typical zone definition looks like this (on the slave server. The master looks a bit simpler):

```
zone "somewebsite.com" {
    masters { ip.ad.dr.ess; };
    type slave;
    allow-query { any; };
    file "slave/db.somewebsite.com";
};
```

The file is filled with about 190 of these. What I needed from each zone was the site name (to use as a sorting key) and the whole string containing the zone. So here are my parsers (and a tiny data type to hold a zone's name and its full text):

```
type SortKey = String
type ZoneText = String
data Zone = Zone SortKey ZoneText deriving Show

allZonesParser :: Parser [Zone]
allZonesParser = do zones <- many zoneParser 
                    return zones

zoneParser :: Parser Zone
zoneParser = do p1 <- string "zone"
                p2 <- many space
                p3 <- string "\""
                zoneName <- many (alphaNum <|> oneOf ".-")
                p4 <- string "\""
                p5 <- many space
                p6 <- manyTill anyChar (try (string ";" >> newline >> string "};"))
                p7 <- many space
                p8 <- many newline
                return $ Zone zoneName (p1 ++ p2 ++ p3 ++ zoneName ++ p4 ++ p5 ++ p6 ++ ";\n};" ++ p7 ++ p8)
```

I realize that this parser will not work for all use cases, but for our zone configuration it was advanced enough. It grabs a whole zone section until it finds `;\n};`, then rebuilds the zone text. And there is my central complaint: I cannot figure out how to retain the entire string representing the zone without using 9 monadic binds, then piecing them together with the `++` operator. Is there an elegant way to consume all this input and retain/use everything that was parsed? I need to use the parsed string later to write a new sorted zone configuration file, and it seems ridiculous to "reconstruct" the string the way that I have done here. I have read through a significant portion of the [Parsec documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.5) without finding a proper way to piece this together.

My full code is [here](https://gist.github.com/MortimerMcMire315/c793e49ae41d715dea92#file-sortzones-hs). I would advise against using it unless you modify it to fit the way your zone configuration is spaced and newlined.

Comment: Why not parse the zone specification to a custom data type then have a dedicated pretty printer for that type?  Do you really need to preserve indentation and whitespace when printing it back out?

Comment: Another note on your full code, you define `compareZone`, but you instead could use the same implementation to define an `Ord` instead for `Zone`, and then you can just use `sort` instead of `sortBy compareZone`.  Just replace `compareZone`'s signature with `instance Ord Zone where`, indent `compareZone's definition over, and rename it to `compare`, then replace `sortBy compareZone` with `sort`.  I would consider this more idiomatic Haskell

Comment: @bheklilr Thanks for the response! I think that makes a lot of sense for a bigger general-purpose script, but I'm trying to figure out what a more elegant solution would have been in this use case. If I had a data type to fully represent a zone definition, I would end up with an arguably more correct but seemingly overengineered script. Am I misinterpreting your comment?

As for your 2nd comment: I entirely agree, and thanks for the suggestion. That was simply blindness on my part.

Comment: It would be more work, and for your case it might be considered over-engineered.  If you want to avoid that, you could instead resort to some simpler techniques Haskell provides.  Parse the first line, find the last, and store all the text in between.  Use `lines` to get each line, then strip off whitespace, prepend `"    "` to each, then use `unlines` to join them all back together.  Then you don't need all the binds.  You should also look at the `between` combinator, it'd help with your quote problem.

Comment: I wish I could award you an answer for that. Yeah, I'm still kind of new to Haskelly ways of thinking, and this was my first time being brave enough to use it in a sysadmin script. So what I'm picking up is that the question I'm asking is not really something that Parsec was designed to do. I can accept that. I will try rewriting the parsing function using your ideas for the sake of my own education.

Comment: I'm not saying it's wrong to use Parsec for this task, it just seems easier to use some of the built-in functionality of Haskell instead.  You can certainly do this with parsec, and it's likely to work better as you add features to the script (if you add features, that is), but for a quick-and-dirty there's other tools I'd consider easier

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do this a lot shorter using Parsec, here's what I've come up with

```
zoneParse = do
    string "zone"
    space1 <- many space
    zoneName <- between (char '"') (char '"') (many $ noneOf "\"")
    body <- manyTill anyChar (try $ string ";\n};")
    return $ Zone zoneName $ concat ["zone", space1, "\"", zoneName, "\"", body, ";\n};"]
```

Here, I've reduced the number of binds to perform because some of them are just capturing a string literal and can be manually inserted later.  I've also used `between` to capture the `zoneName` since it's a rather handy combinator in Parsec.  After that, it's just parsing out all the characters until `;\n};` is spotted (does the same as `string ";" >> newline >> string "};"` if you don't have `\r\n` in your files, otherwise stick with the version with `newline`), then rebuilding the string using `concat`